# How to select features, using python, when dataframe has features in rows

Tags: python, random-forest

My data frame is like this: Where px1, px2,...px99 are placeholders and appear in data frame as columns. It has values like 5569, 5282 etc, which are real features to be selected. These features are in many thousands. I want to filter important features. Trying to use Random Forest. I know I can filter Px's from Random Forest but how actual features embedded within? I am using python.

**px1       px2    px3   px4    px5  px6    px7     px8     px9   px10**

5569    5282    93
5569    5280    93   9904
5569    5282    93   93    3893  8872   3897    9904
5569    5280    5551 93     93   3995   8607
5569    5280    93   8867
5282    5569    93   9904   93

Comment: Be more explicit ! You want to select features for each row or for all raw ? Is columns conditioned ?

Comment: @G.S: I want to select features for all rows (no row specific). I want to build a regression model. For that I want to select important features. I didn't get what do you mean by columns conditioned? Do you mean normalized or scaled? Features represents specific disease, which physician enters when a patient visits a hospital. Each row is an encounter level data for a patient visit to a hospital. For ex: If one visits for appendix operation, then 5569 (in px1 first row) represents for appendix. But, for appendix, patient will go through x-ray (5582), pain-killer (93) etc in the first row.

Comment: I understand. So what you mean about important, you think about distribution's mode ? Do you care about the chronology in the sense that, x-ray before pain-killer is the same as pain-killer before x-ray ?

Comment: @G.S: Chronology does not matter. All codes can occur in any order. The reason for main (important) features selection is: I want to build models for different diseases like Appendix operation. I want to see what all important procedures (codes like 5569, 5280 etc) were performed on different patients when they visited different hospitals. You can see that in row1 there are three procedure codes only where as in row3 there are 8 procedure codes for the same set of diseases. It can go up to 99 of them in each row. Therefore I want to filter the important procedures performed.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need more than 2 column cause chronology doesn't matter,so

```
df = pds.concat([df[['px1',col]].rename(columns={col:'px2'}) for col in df.columns],\
                 axis=0,join='outer').dropna()
```

Now, because you only consider the 1st variable, you have to see:

```
for label,dist in df.groupby('px1')['px2']:
   dist.hist(bins=len(dist.unique()),label=label)
```